# Can I burn CD/DVD/USB reliably from an External USB Hard Drive?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive, dvd, usb-3

Never had an external hard drive before and looking to get one to use across a couple of PC systems.

Can I burn Linux iso to DVD/USB from an external hard drive such as the Toshiba HDTB310EK3AA which uses USB 3.0 with reliability using this type of drive or are the read speeds to low?

https://www.amazon.co.uk/Toshiba-HDTB310EK3AA-Canvio-Portable-External/dp/B00KWHJY7Q/ref=sr_1_2?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1473792606&sr=1-2&keywords=external+hard+drive

Comment: Writing to USB should not be affect by source speed.  You don't mention your OS, but when I was in Windows, Windows cached a copy of what's to be written on a local hard drive before burning optical media, so the original source location doesn't matter.  If you're doing this in Linux, I'm not sure whether Linux also caches locally.

Answer (score 1):

USB 3 has a max transfer of about 625 MB/s. That Toshiba external drive has an SSD in it. SSD can vary but it I have a cheap one that tests out at about 500MB/second when plugged in internally.

A 1x DVD write speed is about 1.3 MB/second, and a quick google shows that 24x DVD write speed is not uncommon. This equates to a max of 31.2 MB/ second.

So **the external drive and USB interface are** each (in theory) capable of **a full order of magnitude faster** reading speed **than the DVD burner**.

In addition to this, all burner software packages use memory buffering to ensure that the data to be written is always ready when the burner needs it, so even if the actual read speed of the USB drive were closer to the write speed of the DVD burner, the buffer is there to make sure it "just works."

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'd have any problems at all.  USB 3.0 is faster than SATA 2.